# Title “References” is missing in elsarticle class

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, elsarticle

I am beginner in LaTeX, and I am trying to use BibTeX to create a reference, I am using  MiKTex 2.9 and TeXstudio 2.5.1 . I am trying to include references to my `.tex` file using BibTeX.

1. I created a .bib file (`mybib.bib`) in TeXstudio using the BibTeX format

   ```
   %%%%%%%%%%%% mybib.bib %%%%%%%%%

   @BOOK{AsmussenandAlbrecher2010,
     author  = {Asmussen, S. and Albrecher, H.},
     title   = {Ruin probabilities},
     edition = {2nd ed.},
     address = {Singapore},
     publisher = {World Scientific},
     year    = {2010}
   }

   @ARTICLE{Botta1987,
     author  = {Botta, R. F. and Harris, C. M. and Marchal, W. G.},
     title   = {Characterisation of generalised hyperexponential distribution functions},
     journal = {Stochastic Models}, 
     volume  = {3},
     year    = {1987},
     pages   = {115-148}
   }

   @BOOK{ChaudhryandTempleton1983,
     author  = {Chaudhry, M. L. and Templeton, J. G. C.},
     title   = {A First Course in Bulk Queues},
     address = {New York},
     publisher = {Wiley},
     year    = {1983}
   }
   ```
2. I include `mybib.bib` in my `.tex` file `test_els.tex`

   ```
   %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% test_els.tex %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
   \documentclass[preprint,12pt]{elsarticle}

   \begin{document}
   \section{Introduction}
   Several researchers studied ruin probability, but for a survey see\cite{AsmussenandAlbrecher2010}.
   For bulk arrival queues see \cite{ChaudhryandTempleton1983}

   \bibliographystyle{model1-num-names}
   \nocite{*}
   \bibliography{mybib}
   \end{document}
   ```
3. I use PDFLATEX->BIBTEX->PDFLATEX->PDFLATEX and the output produced references cited in the text, but the title `references` is missing.
4. Where is the mistake? Please help.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're not doing wrong. The `elsarticle` class uses the `natbib` package that hands control of the bibliography section heading to the command `\bibsection`. In the standard setup of `natbib` this does (inside an article)

```
\section*{\refname}
```

Actually it's a bit more complex than this, but the details are not relevant. The `elsarticle` class does

```
\let\bibsection\relax
```

so I'd say not providing a heading is intentional. Just add a heading yourself:

```
\documentclass[preprint,12pt]{elsarticle}

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}

Several researchers studied ruin probability, but for a survey
see\cite{AsmussenandAlbrecher2010}. For bulk arrival queues see
\cite{ChaudhryandTempleton1983}

\bibliographystyle{model1-num-names}
\nocite{*}

\section{\refname}
\bibliography{mybib}

\end{document}
```

Use `\section*` if you want it unnumbered.

[image]

Comment: Just remember that if this is an article for a journal that asks you to use `elsarticle` then that choice is intentional and you should not mess with it or try to undo it. It just ends up annoying the journal editors.

Comment: Thank you , I got it. How to arrange them alphabetically (no dependency on the order of citations)

Comment: @litun that depends on the bibliography style you use. There might be others that came along with `elsarticle`. (Just noticed that one of the authors you cite is a colleague of mine)

Comment: Who is? I am using {model1-num-names.bst} of elsevier

Comment: Asmussen. The `elsarticle.zip` one can download from Sprint contains 13 `bibtex` styles. `modelX-num-names` for `X=1,1a,1b,1c,3,3a,6`, `modelY-names`, for `Y=2,4,5` plus `elsarticle-Z` for `Z=harv,num,num-names`

Comment: He is a great fellow. About bibtex styles, I have already downloaded and using manuscript preparation. The problem is in alphabetical ordering the references.