# Why is this elsarticle code not correctly compiling my .bib file?

Tags: elsarticle

I'm using an example code from a [previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/137371/title-references-is-missing-in-elsarticle-class).

The code for the elsarticle document class from that past question is:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% test_els.tex %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\documentclass[preprint,12pt]{elsarticle}

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
Several researchers studied ruin probability, but for a survey see\cite{AsmussenandAlbrecher2010}.
For bulk arrival queues see \cite{ChaudhryandTempleton1983}

\bibliographystyle{model1-num-names}
\section{\refname}

\nocite{*}
\bibliography{mybib}

\end{document}
```

I copied that word-for-word into my MiKTeX. Accompanying that was my .bib file (mybib):

```
%%%%%%%%%%%% mybib.bib %%%%%%%%%

@BOOK{AsmussenandAlbrecher2010,
  author  = {Asmussen, S. and Albrecher, H.},
  title   = {Ruin probabilities},
  edition = {2nd ed.},
  address = {Singapore},
  publisher = {World Scientific},
  year    = {2010}
}

@ARTICLE{Botta1987,
  author  = {Botta, R. F. and Harris, C. M. and Marchal, W. G.},
  title   = {Characterisation of generalised hyperexponential distribution functions},
  journal = {Stochastic Models}, 
  volume  = {3},
  year    = {1987},
  pages   = {115-148}
}

@BOOK{ChaudhryandTempleton1983,
  author  = {Chaudhry, M. L. and Templeton, J. G. C.},
  title   = {A First Course in Bulk Queues},
  address = {New York},
  publisher = {Wiley},
  year    = {1983}
}
```

After saving that .bib, I ran the .tex file in MiKTeX (PDFLatex > BibTex > PDFLatex > PDFLatex). I cannot seem to avoid getting [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y096t.jpg) output. The code is so simple, yet I can't find what I'm doing wrong. Any advice?

Comment: The `elsarticle` document class is currently distributed with the bibliography style files `elsarticle-num.bst`, `elsarticle-num-names.bst`, and `elsarticle-harv.bst`. The style `model1-num-names` no longer seems to be distributed with `elsarticle`.

Comment: Is the bibliographystyle command a requirement? I took it out completely and still had the same output.

Comment: The `\bibliographystyle` command is absolutely required if you're working with BibTeX. (If you delete the command, be sure to also delete the aux files to see the full effect.)

Comment: Just tested with the bst file found on some university server, works like a charm. I vote to close as unclear, as there was no further reaction by the OP.